# Multiple Image Upload using Ajax with Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, image-uploading

First I want Apology for my eng.

Second I don't want to use any plugin.

I Want to upload Multiple image and I can do it without ajax, But I want to upload with Ajax.
I Put my Code here.

```
<form action="{{route('image-upload.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {{csrf_field()}}
   <input type="file" id="image-upload" name="image_upload[]" enctype="multipart/form-data" multiple>  

  <button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
```

Controller :

```
if ($request->hasFile('image_upload')) {
        $images = $request->file('image_upload');
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $randonName = rand(1, 200);
            $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $storename = $randonName . '_' . $name;
            $image->move(public_path('images/test'), $storename);
        }
    }

return redirect()->back();
```

Above Code simply upload multiple image without Ajax.

Here Ajax :

html :

```
 <input type="file" id="image-upload" name="image_upload[]" enctype="multipart/form-data" multiple>
```

Ajax :

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
 });

$('#image-upload').change(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    let image_upload = new FormData();
    let TotalImages = $('#image-upload')[0].files.length;  //Total Images
    let images = $('#image-upload')[0];  

    for (let i = 0; i < TotalImages; i++) {
        image_upload.append('images', images.files[i]);
    }
    image_upload.append('TotalImages', TotalImages);

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/image-upload',
        data: image_upload,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (images) {
            console.log(`ok ${images}`)
        },
        error: function () {
          console.log(`Failed`)
        }
    })

})
```

Controller :

```
  if ($request->images) {
        $images = $request->images;
        $total=$request->TotalImages;
        $imagesName = $images->getClientOriginalName();
       $randonName = rand(1, 200);
        $images->move(public_path('/images/test'), $randonName . '.jpg');
        return response()->json($randonName);
    }
```

Now This Code Work Fine but only for one image. I know that I Sould put it `Loop` and I did But didn't get my Response.

So if anyone can tell me how do it?

Here My Efforts :

```
 if ($request->images) {
       $total=$request->TotalImages;
        $images = $request->images;
        for($j=0; $j<$total;$j++){
            $imagesName = $images->getClientOriginalName();
            $randonName = rand(1, 200);
            $images->move(public_path('/images/test'), $randonName . '.jpg');
        }
        return response()->json($randonName);
    }

  if ($request->images) {
        $images = $request->images;
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $imagesName = $images->getClientOriginalName();
            $randonName = rand(1, 200);
            $image->move(public_path('/images/test'),$randonName . $imagesName . $randonName . '.jpg');
        }
    }
```

Comment: For this $request->images variable what you get output ?

Comment: return response()->json($request->images);   .Output is an object ( [object Object] )

Comment: can you please post response in your question?

Comment: thanks but i found problem.     just need replace this simple ajax code :   image_upload.append('images[]', images.files[i]);

Comment: Then post an answer that will help others or delete this question

Comment: Hi siros, could you help me out with something, I always get 'Field access via magic method' on my phpstorm in your code:  if ($request->images) ... and i think because of that nothing works, do you know why?. regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your code as follows:

```
for (let i = 0; i < TotalImages; i++) {
    image_upload.append('images', images.files[i]);
}
```

to

```
for (let i = 0; i < TotalImages; i++) {
    image_upload.append('images' + i, images.files[i]);
}
```

this should help you to submit multiple images.

Comment: If you put +i in the iteration...formdata will add the number of iterations in front of the name file....so images0...images1 etc...how will you read this on server side?

Answer (score 3):

this gonna work too this will send array of images so as to get it easily in controller

```
        for (let i = 0; i < TotalImages; i++) {
            image_upload.append('images[]', images.files[i]);
        }
```